# Mixed-Integer Linear Programing : get the maximum constant associated to a non null variable

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, integer-programming

Does anyone know a way get the maximum constant associated to a non null variable using Mixed-Integer Linear Programing ?

I would like to get the variable $a$ in this description :
$$ i = 1,\ldots,m $$
$$ C_{i}, B : constants $$
$$ x_{i} : variables $$
$$ C_{i}, B \gt 0 $$
$$ x_{i} \in 0 \cup [B; +\infty] $$
$$ a = \max_i (C_i \text{ when } x_{i} > 0) $$
$$ a = 0 \quad \text{if there is no } x_{i} > 0 $$

Getting $a$ must not change the validity of an existing objective function.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What do you know about $x$,$y$, $z$. Integer? Upper and lower bounds?

Comment: They are semi-continuous variables. x, y, z e 0 U [1; +inf].
I already handle this using branch-and-bound

Comment: Are you modelling the semi-continuous behavior manually with some binary variable, or are you using built-in features for that

Comment: In fact I am not modelling this. I solve the continuous problem using my home made simplex first and then I re-solve the problem adding new constraints on the bounds if necessary, using dual simplex.

Comment: A home made manual implementation of branch-and-bound if you want

Comment: What should happen in the 5 other cases?

Comment: Ok sorry I forgot 1 of the 8 cases in my example : the case where all the 3 variables are 0. The example was just to understand the "get the maximum constant associated to a non null variable" sentence. I change the description to write this sentence mathematically if it could help